# not a statement error, illegal start of type

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class ulang {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        int a;
        int b;
        int sum;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter num 1: ");
        a = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter num 2: ");
        b = in.nextLine();
        {
            sum = a + b;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            (sum >= 10)
                System.out.println("Congratulations");
            else
                System.out.println("Sum of the number is Less than 10");
        }

    }
}
```

I'm weak on looping especially in Java. So I need some corrections on my coding, but I have no idea how to fix it.

The coding should run like this: User need to insert 2 numbers and the program will calculate the sum of both number. After that, the program will determine if the total of sum is >=10 or <10. If the sum >=10, "Congratulations" will appear but if it is <10, then "The sum of number less than 10" will appear. How to fix it?

Comment: You're missing an if before (sum>=10)

Comment: I took the liberty to fix your indentation for you (not fixed any of the compiler bugs, however).

Comment: And what's the loop for? Why are you printing out the same message 5 times?

Comment: In the future, note that error messages come equipped with a line number.  It's often fairly useful.

Answer (score 7):

This is the immediate problem:

```
(sum>=10)
```

I believe you meant that to be an `if` statement:

```
if (sum>=10)
```

Additionally:

- You're trying to use an `in` variable, but the Scanner variable is called `scan`
- `Scanner.nextLine()` returns a `String` - I suspect you wanted `Scanner.nextInt()`
- Your `for` loop uses a variable that hasn't been declared. You probably meant:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  ```

A few other suggestions though:

- The sum isn't going to change between the loop iterations... why are you looping at all?
- You've got a new block in which you're calculating the sum, but for no obvious reason. Why?
- It's generally a good idea to declare variables at the point of initialization, e.g.

  ```
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter num 1: ");
  int a = scan.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Enter num 2: ");
  int b = scan.nextInt();
  int sum = a + b;
  ```
- Given that you want to take the same basic action (writing a message to the screen) whether or not the user was successful, you might *consider* using the conditional operator like this:

  ```
  String message = sum >= 10 ? "Congratulations"
                             : "Sum of the number is Less than 10";
  System.out.println(message);
  ```

  That would then allow you to refactor the loop to only evaluate the condition once:

  ```
  String message = sum >= 10 ? "Congratulations"
                             : "Sum of the number is Less than 10";
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
      System.out.println(message);
  }
  ```

Comment: ok i fix it already ,,i put if (sum>=10).. but still got an error " 'else' without 'if',<identifier> expected , class interface or enum expected , illegal start of type,...all this error in looping. why ?

Comment: @EzwanAbid: It's not clear how you changed it, but using `if (sum >= 10)` *does* work, believe me. That problem has nothing to do with the looping, although your `for` loop *does* have a problem (you haven't declared `i`) as I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: ahh forgot to tell u ...i make loop because i want loop the program for 5 times.. i mean from User input until the output(Congratulations / Less than 10) ...i need to do it 5 times..thats why i make loop

Comment: @EzwanAbid: Well then you need to change where you're looping, don't you? Currently you're *only* going to loop around the final part. It sounds like you might want a loop which covers pretty much the whole of the `main` method. You might even want to pull all the work into a separate method, and then make your `main` method *just* a loop which calls the method within the loop.

Comment: ahh now i mention it ..i only loop the  Output section..and the Input section i didnt bring it to loop..am i right ? so all i need to do is bring the input section into Looping? just copy and paste on it ?

Comment: @EzwanAbid: No, you need to *move* it, not *copy* it. Your loop would have to include the *whole* of the logic of the method, basically. As I said though, it would be cleaner to put all that logic into one method which you *call* from a loop.

Comment: oouuuh..now i understand what u mean. Anyway thank for helping me... if u have some link or file for Java Tutorials that can share..can u give it to me ..i need some review.. If u dont have ..its ok . :) thanks again..lot of help from u @Jon Skeet

Answer (score 1):

`(sum>=10)`

This line needs an if at the beginning, or it won't be read as a branch.

`if (sum >= 10)`

You also should name your main-class Ulang, because java class identifiers should start with an upper case letter, for readability.

The loop should look like the following:

`for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {`

The first part defines the counter and assigns zero to it. The second is your condition and the last counts for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (sum >= 10)
        System.out.println("Congratulations");
    else
        System.out.println("Sum of the number is Less than 10");
}
```